# How to pass azure pipeline variable to mysql stored procedure query in look up activity

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, lookup

I have to call a stored procedure in lookup activity of Azure Data Factory for mysql that takes azure pipeline variable as input but i dont know the exact syntax.

Like call stored_prpcedure("@variables('BAtchID')")

The variable is of string type

If anyone knows how exactly i can call it?
Please do share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly use `call stored_prpcedure("@variables('BAtchID')")` in your *query* section of **Look up** activity.

- The query field expects a string value, when you use `call stored_prpcedure("@variables('BAtchID')")` directly, it will be parsed as is but not as a pipeline variable.
- Instead, you need to concatenate the query with pipeline variable using `@concat()` function in data factory.
- The following is a demonstration of how I used query field to execute stored procedure using dynamic content.

[image]

- You can use the dynamic content below to successfully achieve your requirement (replace stored procedure name and variable name)

```
@concat('call demo("',variables('value_to_pass'),'")')
```

[image]

- The above content will be parsed as `call demo("Welcome")` which is shown below (`\` indicates escape character):

[image]

**Note:** The debug run in the above image failed because I don't have a stored procedure in mysql database.

Comment: I tried the above method you suggested but I'm getting following error:

Comment: ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The value of the property 'columns' is invalid: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: columns'.,Source=,''Type=System.ArgumentNullException,Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: columns,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'

Comment: Hi Saideep, your answer/solutiom really helped me  thank you so much for the time and efforts